# Regex for a string starting with http:// and containing ~

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate a string with regex in javascript that a user inputs into a `<form>`that starts with `http://` and contains a `~` somwhere within that string.
what I have is

`(/^(http?:\/\/)\~/.test(string))`

But it's not quite working.

Any tips?

Comment: `If ( str.indexOf('http://') === 0 && str.indexOf('~') > 0 )` ???

Comment: @adeneo Thanks that worked! Can you explain how indexOf works? and what's the difference between == and ===?

Comment: @Enigma it gives you the starting index of the substring in the given string..

Comment: [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) gives you the index of the string inside the string. If that index is `0`, the string starts with that string. If it's more than `0` it contains the string, if it's `-1` it does *not* contain the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex solution would look like:

```
(/^https?:\/\/.*\~/.test(string))
```

Your regex was almost correct, you were just missing the `.*` which checks for characters after the `http://` portion

I also put `s?` in there in-case `https` was valid

Comment: Why did you escape `~` actually?

Comment: Well honestly, I included the escape because the OP had it escaped. Figured it might be special in JS. Does it hurt anything? I know it worked in the console when I tested it.

Answer (score 3):

No need or RegEx, you can use [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

```
if (str.startsWith('http://') && str.includes('~')) {
```

As these methods are not supported by all the browsers, you can use polyfills from MDN for older browsers.

Comment: Cool, that worked as well! It's neat how there's multiple methods to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your regex should be repaired to this:

```
(/^(http?:\/\/).*\~/.test(string))
```